# How to create a route link for scrolling to an in-page element?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

Let's say I have a page with an element like this:

```
...
<div id="dummy">
</div>
...
```

I can create a link that scrolls to `#dummy` like this `http://website.com/page#dummy`.

My question is, how could I make a link in the form of `http://website.com/page/dummy` and behaves exactly the same as the above link (links to page and just scrolls to `#dummy`)?

Also I want the url of the page to change to `http://website.com/page/dummy` if the user scrolled to `#dummy` element.

Is there something readily available in Next.js or React that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects). Just create `next.config.js` and add following configuration

```
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/page/:slug",
                destination: "/page#:slug",
                permanent: true,
            },
        ];
    },
};
```